# Heatmaply sidebar colors, how to show specified colors correctly?

Tags: r, plotly, sidebar, heatmaply

I have a problem, might be a bug in heatmaply or plotly. Colors in the sidebar of a heatmap are not showing the colors I specified. See the code example below, At the end of the code in part # 6) the first plot, plotted using the plot function (simple plot showing the colors), shows the colors correctly (yellow and blue):

[image]

The second plot using these colors in a heatmaply side bar (heatmamply side bar with wrong color):

[image]

fails to show them correctly and instead what appears to show random colors. In a similar plot with real data there are even red and orange colors in the sidebar (heatmaply sidebar shows red and orange while color range is blue-yellow):

[image]

while all codes are generated using a blue yellow color range. Any ideas what might cause this bug and how to show colors in the sidebar consistent with their color code a?

### Compare cophenetic similarity between leaves in two trees build on full data and subsample of the data

```
# 1 ) Generate random data to build trees
set.seed(2015-04-26)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 50) # Dataframe with 50 columns
datSubSample <- dat[, sample(ncol(dat), 30)] #Dataframe with 30 columns sampled from the dataframe with 50
dat_dist1 <- dist(datSubSample)
dat_dist2 <- dist(dat)
hc1 <- hclust(dat_dist1)
hc2 <- hclust(dat_dist2)

# 2) Build two dendrograms, one based on all data, second based a sample of the data (30 out of 50 columns)
dendrogram1 <- as.dendrogram(hc1)
dendrogram2 <- as.dendrogram(hc2)

# 3) For each leave in a tree get cophenetic distance matrix, 
# each column represent distance of that leave to all others in the same tree
cophDistanceMatrix1 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(cophenetic(dendrogram1)))
cophDistanceMatrix2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(cophenetic(dendrogram2)))

# 4) Calculate correlation between cophenetic distance of a leave to all other leaves, between two trees
corPerLeave <- NULL # Vector to store correlations for each leave in two trees
for (leave in colnames(cophDistanceMatrix1)){
  cor <- cor(cophDistanceMatrix2[leave], cophDistanceMatrix1[leave])
  corPerLeave <- c(corPerLeave, unname(cor))
}

# 5) Convert cophenetic correlation to color to show in side bar of a heatmap
corPerLeave <- corPerLeave / max(corPerLeave) #Scale 0 to 1 correlation
byPal <- colorRampPalette(c('yellow', 'blue')) #blue yellow color palette, low correlation = yellow
colCopheneticCor <- byPal(20)[as.numeric(cut(corPerLeave, breaks =20))]

# 6) Plot heatmap with dendrogram with side bar that shows cophenetic correlation for each leave 
row_dend  <- dendrogram2
x  <- as.matrix(dat_dist2)
#### Plot belows use the same color code, normal plot works, however heatmaply shows wrong colors
plot(x = 1:length(colCopheneticCor), y = 1:length(colCopheneticCor), col = colCopheneticCor)
heatmaply(x, colD = row_dend, row_side_colors = colCopheneticCor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, you can use a function for the color with the heatmaply build in *row_side_palette* parameter. Minimal example code, that can be combined with the code in the question itself to show heatmap with cophenetic distance per leave/species in the sidebar represented by a different color:

```
ByPal <- colorRampPalette(c('red','blue')) # Bi color palette function to be used in sidebar 

heatmaply(m,colD = row_dend, file=fileName1, plot_method= "plotly",colorscale='Viridis',row_side_palette= byPal ,
                row_side_colors=data.frame("Correlation cophenetic distances" = corPerLeave, check.names=FALSE))
```

One problem I did not solve yet is how to show a continuous colorbar in the legend, any suggestions?